# How to change the database credentials using docker

Tags: docker-compose

I see that the database credentials are stored in the context.xml file.  How to set this via a docker environment variable?

E.g. this does not work:

```
  scadalts:
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=somethingelse
```

(also set the same in the database container as:
`MYSQL_PASSWORD=somethingelse`)